# How can I get the MethodInfo of Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression, ParameterExpression[])?

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, expression

I'm trying to get the `MethodInfo` of the static [Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression, ParameterExpression[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda#system-linq-expressions-expression-lambda-1(system-linq-expressions-expression-system-linq-expressions-parameterexpression())) method. But I'm getting an `AmbiguousMatchException` when I try with `GetMetod`:

```
MethodInfo lambda = typeof(Expression).GetMethod(nameof(Expression.Lambda), new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(ParameterExpression[]) });
```

I have figured out a very convoluted way by getting all public static methods and filtering:

```
MethodInfo lambda = (
    from m in typeof(Expression).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    let p = ((MethodBase)m.ReturnParameter.Member).GetParameters()
    where m.Name == nameof(Expression.Lambda) && m.ReturnType.IsGenericType 
                                              && p.Length == 2 
                                              && p[0].ParameterType == typeof(Expression) 
                                              && p[1].ParameterType == typeof(ParameterExpression[])
    select m
).Single();
```

It works but seems overly complicated and pretty dangerous (cast to `MethodBase` plus `Single()` call).

Is there a simpler solution to get that generic `MethodInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the number of type parameters to the `GetMethod` call, this will uniquely identify a generic method (because you can't have two methods with the same number of generic type parameters, but you can have with a different number).

```cs
var method = typeof(Expression)
    .GetMethod(
      nameof(Expression.Lambda),
      1,
      new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(ParameterExpression[]) }
    );
```

[**dotnetfiddle.net**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ClWtW1)

Comment: How did I miss this overload of `GetMethod`? 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can obtain the `MethodInfo` by instantiating a `Func` matching the signature, then getting the method info of a closed generic version of `Expression.Lambda` (e.g. closed on `object`) and finally getting the generic method definition:

```
MethodInfo lambda = new Func<Expression, ParameterExpression[], Expression<object>>(Expression.Lambda<object>)
    .GetMethodInfo()
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

The `MethodInfo` is the same as the one you obtained by filtering (the `MetadataToken` are identical).

Comment: There's a checkbox titled `Answer your own question` when asking a question and a link to [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). That's basically how I blog about programming stuff. 